# GIDSignInDelegate method stub is giving an error

Tags: ios, swift

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    //ERROR: Candidate has non-matching type '(GIDSignIn!, GIDGoogleUser!, Error!) -> ()'
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    }
}
```

I added a method that conforms to the `GIDSignInDelegate` but it gives me an error saying:

> Type 'SignUpViewController' does not conform to protocol 'GIDSignInDelegate'. Candidate has non-matching type '(GIDSignIn!, GIDGoogleUser!, Error!) -> ().

I am not sure how to fix this since this is the exact same method that showed up in the auto completion. Did the signature of the protocol method for `GIDSignInDelegate` change since?

Answer (score 1):

The error was not in the signature of the method but rather explained here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/267. If you look under evelynklassen comment:

> I had a model with the name "Error", it was probably conflicting with GoogleSignIn.

This was my case as well since I had another class in my project named `Error` which was conflicting with the `error` object passed in the protocol method above which also is of type `Error`.

Hope this can help others.